# Automate gdb: show backtrace at every call to function puts

Tags: gdb

I want to debug some program. I need backtraces from all calls to some function, e.g. puts.

Now I use such gdb `script`:

```
set width 0
set height 0
set verbose off
break puts
commands 1
backtrace
continue
end
```

But starting it with

```
gdb --batch --command=script --args ./some_program arguments
```

Gives a error:

```
Function "puts" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
/root/script:5: Error in sourced command file:
No breakpoint number 1.
```

How can I set breakpoint in script for library call?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
set width 0
set height 0
set verbose off
start  # runs to main, so shared libraries are loaded
       # after you reach main, GDB should have libc symbols, "puts" among them
break puts
commands 1
backtrace
continue
end
```

If this doesn't work, please state operating system version.

EDIT: as osgx correctly points out, the other alternative is to add

```
set breakpoint pending on
```

before `break puts`

Comment: And what about " breakpoint pending" setting?  А еще - спасибо.

Comment: You can use `start` instead of `break main; run`

Comment: On my system, the `start` command created a breakpoint, so `commands` needed `2` instead of `1`.