# How to read and execute GDB commands from a file?

Tags: gdb, gnu, disassembly

I run **GDB** on **object file** (e.g `exeFile`) and I want to examine it according to several commands  .  How can I execute these commands according to lines in a file (instead input these each **GDN** running) ?

For example - 
I want to set break in  -

```
break *0x8048e19
break *0x8048e32
break *0x8048e6f
break *0x8048e90
```

so I want to save them in a file and then tell the GDB execute them from this file.

Comment: Slightly more generic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/automating-gdb-sessions

Answer (score 75, accepted):

write the commands in a file and execute gdb with -x switch

```
gdb -x command_file_name
```

or run the gdb source command while gdb is running if you dont want to specify a command file from command line

```
>source [-s] [-v] command_file_name
```

Comment: How do I write it bindding with the object file( `exeFile`) ?

Comment: you can load object file using as one of the command in commands file.

Comment: Here's the official documentation on these GDB "command files": https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html.