# How to run program in gdb via bashscript with backtrace?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, gdb

I'm trying to run my program TestApc via gdb and get useful data when my program crash with back trace command ("bt" command).

I wrote a bash script , which look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
gdb -ex=r --args ./TestApc
```

When the program crash, I can't type the "bt" command (because I get out from the gdb console)
Is there a way to stay on gdb after the crash ?

Comment: Is there any specific need of executing gdb through a bash script. From command line it will be much easier.

Comment: You may find some help here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/automating-gdb-sessions

Comment: When the program crashes, you should see a `(gdb)` prompt. Are you seeing something else?

Comment: After the prograam crash - I can see it was exsits from the gdb console

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?