# Capture gdb output with ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, gdb

I tried to do that :

```
a = `gdb -q ./test` ; print a
```

But it's showing nothing, even the gdb process are running. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gdb` waits for some command after start entered from `stdin`. At least, `r` to run program. So you need to send `r` to `gdb`. Try this:

```
a = `echo 'r'|gdb -q ./test`; print a
```

Also, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/what-are-the-best-ways-to-automate-a-gdb-debugging-session)