# ltrace and gdb attach to same process

Tags: debugging, gdb, ltrace

Is it somehow possible to use `ltrace` and `gdb` at the same time? I have a small stripped binary program, where I would like to see the variable contents, of some library calls I can see with `ltrace`.

Is it somehow possible to attach gdb and ltrace to the same process?

Comment: What OS? If Linux, you can use systemtap to emulate ltrace. https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/ltrace.stp

Answer (score 2):

No, both gdb and ltrace use [`ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) to debug and trace process, and tracee (target) process may be attached only to single ptrace tracer.

You may try implement some call tracing inside gdb with `breakpoint function_name` or `b function_addr`, getting breakpoint id and adding gdb [`commands` to execute at this breakpoint](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#), for example for breakpoint with number 1:

```
  commands 1
  bt 2
  p/x $rax
  continue
```

gdb will print backtrace (bt), and rax register value, then it will [continue](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping) execution (more examples and disabling of pagination is at [What are the best ways to automate a GDB debugging session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/)).

Or you can try in-kernel tracing solution like `sysdig`.

Comment: Hey @osgx, I have an interesting proposal for you. Do you think you could send me an email: s@lambdal.com? I know this isn’t the right forum for this but I couldn’t find your contact info anywhere. Cheers.

Comment: @sabalaba, Which kind of proposal? CID key: 980ee28f810afceb