# How to write a bash script that executes gdb on a program

Tags: c, bash, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am recreating the buffer overflow from http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Software/Buffer_Overflow/Buffer_Overflow.pdf and I would like to write a bash script that will gdb on my "stack" executable. The script will then make break points and grab the addresses of the begging (p &buffer) and end (p $ebp) of the buffer that the will be passed into ./exploit <&buffer, $ebp> as arguments.

When I run my script..

```
#!/bin/sh
gdb stack
b main
b 14
run
b 23
c
p &buffer
p $ebp
```

When I use it, gdb is opened on my executable. However, the rest of the script is not executed. I assume this is because gdb creates a new process. I have tried " gdb stack "$$" " to get gdb on the same process as my script, however unsuccessful.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Edit:

New Script: This correctly outputs the addresses to the command line

```
#!/bin/sh
gdb stack << 'EOF'
  b main
  run
  b 23
  c
  s
  p &buffer
  p $ebp
  quit
EOF
```

How do I grab those addresses so I can pass them in as arguments to ./exploit?

Following line of my bash file will be..

```
./exploit <&buffer> <$ebp>
```

Comment: Each line in the shell script as written is a shell command — so when `gdb` exits, the shell running the script will attempt to run commands `b`, `run`, `c`, `p`, `buffer`, etc.  You need to redirect the subsequent lines to the input of `gdb`; use a here document `gdb stack <<'EOF'` followed by your `gdb` commands, and then a line containing only `EOF` (left justified).

Comment: That worked! I have just made an edit with a new question.

Comment: You probably need to redirect standard output (from `gdb`) to a file: `gdb <<'EOF' >gdb.output` to place the information in `gdb.output`.  You will then have to worry about cleaning the data to get the two addresses.  ASLR may mess things up for you — beware.

Comment: Dunno — they invented these things called '[manuals](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/)' that help explain how programs work.  I'd have to read it to find the answer; since it isn't my problem, I'm delegating the reading process to you.  You might be able to use something like `p &buffer >buffer.out`.  But I make no promises — I've not read the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gdb -batch yourfile
```

as supossed in `man gdb`.

Or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/what-are-the-best-ways-to-automate-a-gdb-debugging-session) for an example.