# Automate GDB to print stack frame at a particular breakpoint

Tags: c, gdb

Is it possible to have gdb attached to the PID of a running process and every time the program hits a particular breakpoint have gdb output the stackframe to an external file?

I've had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388799/automate-gdb-show-backtrace-at-every-call-to-function-puts) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/automating-gdb-sessions?lq=1) but there is no mention on whether it is possible to attach gdb to an already running process (instead of having gdb launch it).

I can otherwise attach gdb to the PID just fine, but I'd like to automate it to run `bt`, store the output in an external file and then run `continue`. At the moment I'm doing this manually and it's a pain when I have to do it every time a breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty direct :) It's just that it seemed like gdb could be automated to carry out some commands when it launches a program, and since you can examine a running pid in much the same way as one that you've just launched it felt like it was possible.

Comment: Well of course it is possible to attach gdb to a running process. It is basic required functionality of any debugger. Have you tried `man gdb`? It's there.

Comment: @Nobilis and I am wrong you got some promising answers

Comment: @n.m. I can attach it just fine, that's not the problem. The problem is that I want it to automatically print the stackframe when the program hits a breakpoint and store the output in an external file. Ideally have gdb run bt when the program hits a breakpoint`, save the output of bt somewhere and then run continue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Is it possible to have gdb attached to the PID of a running process??
```

Yes. Possible.

**Updated:**

Step 1:

In **.gdbinit** file add the following command,

```
define callstack
     set $Cnt = $arg0

     while($Cnt)
        commands $Cnt
        silent
        bt
        c
        end
        set $Cnt = $Cnt - 1
     end
end
```

Step 2: Invoke the gdb with `-x <path to .gdbinit file >`. Remember PID also for running process.

Step 3: Put Break points, whereever you need.

Step 4: Call the user defined command `callstack` and pass no .of break points.

```
    gdb> callstack <No.of. Break Points>
```

Step 5: Now give 'c' to continue. Bcos process is already running.

For **Logging** I suggest to follow @VoidPointer's answer.

```
set pagination off
set logging file gdb.txt
set logging on
```

works for me. [Reference](http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.com/).

Comment: I should probably clarify that I have access to the source and the program is compiled with debug symbols so when I attach gdb to it, I can set up breakpoints freely, have a look at the functions, when printing the stack frame I get all the names etc. Will this make any difference?

Comment: The above steps put the break point to all the functions in your process. Those function names will be in `function_names` file. For collection function names, I'm using `nm` tools which needs object file, not executable. so you need to generate object files using -c option.

Comment: I only want a breakpoint at a particular line, as I have debugging symbols I can access the line just fine and set a breakpoint there. I won't need all the function names in there. Is it possible to just set a breakpoint, run backtrace there and then store that output?

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try this and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong can you please help me? I ran gdb like this ` gdb -p 3580 -x ./.gdbinit` after I saved the code in the gdbinit file. I set a breakpoint where I needed (`b sourcefile.c:3535`), called `callstack 1` and then `run` and the program exited. Also how do I print the results of `callstack` to an external file? Is it possible to say have `gdb` run in the background and have stdout redirected to a file? Thanks!

Comment: Process is already running right?? so just give `c` after `callstack 1`.

Answer (score 6):

If what you need is to automate printing stack-frame using gdb when knowing PID and functions then you can try this.. (Given minimal code to be functional)

**/root/.gdb_init:**

```
set pagination off
set logging file gdb.txt
set logging on

br fun_convert
# ^^ when breaking at function fun_convert, execute `commands` till next `end`
commands
    bt
    print "Sample print command 1 \n"
    continue
end

br file.c:451
# ^^ when breaking at line 451 of file.c, execute from `commands` till next `end`
commands
    bt
    print "Sample print command 2 \n"
    continue
end

continue
```

Invoking GDB for PID `6474` and command file `/root/.gdb_init`,

```
gdb -p 6474 -x /root/.gdb_init
```

Here, `fun_convert` is the function to break. This `br` is actual `break` gdb-command and you can also break at any line of file using `br file.c:451`. For more `break` options, check gdb help. You can add any gdb-commands you need between `commands` and `end` for corresponding `br`. For more info on `commands`, check `help commands` on *gdb*.

*Note: SO's JS is broken on my browser, please pardon any mistakes and feel free to correct. Also can't add comments :(*

Comment: Cool, how do I run this from the command line, sorry? Also, does this depend on the breakpoint I've set or whenever `fun_convert` for example is called?

Comment: For example instead of `b fun_convert` can I do `b 451` where 451 is the line number?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I chose Jeyaram's solution as this worked for me but I upvoted your answer for the `set` commands you had provided :)